# Finding Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I couldn't  calculate $$\int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-itx}}{2\pi} \frac{1}{a^2+x^2} dx. $$

I can either turn this into something along the lines of $\large \int \limits_0^{\pi/2} \cos( t \cdot \tan x ) dx$ or $ \large  \int \limits_0^{+\infty} \frac{\cos tx}{a + ix} dx$ neither of which I can solve.

I've been told, that some tools of complex calculus could simplify this, but my book hasn't covered any before giving the exercise, so I wonder if there is a way without it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrals containing $a^2 + x^2$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution#Integrals_containing_a2_.E2.88.92_x2

Answer (score 2):

Its better we use duality property of Fourier transform. It says that if $$f(t)\Longleftrightarrow F(ix)$$ then $$F(it)\Longleftrightarrow 2\pi f(-x)$$Thus by knowing that $$\dfrac{1}{2a}e^{-a|t|}\Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{a^2+x^2}$$,
by invoking duality, we get $$\dfrac{1}{a^2+t^2}\Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{\pi}{a}e^{-a|x|}$$Hope this helps.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you may find the initial Fourier transform in any [table](http://www.ibk.ethz.ch/ch/education/identmeth/fourier.pdf).